# How can an asynchronously loaded module get the latest value from a Bacon.js Bus?

Tags: javascript, amd, bacon.js

I have a `Bacon.Bus` within an AMD module.

```
define( 'bus', [ 'bacon' ], function( Bacon ){
    return new Bacon.Bus();
} );
```

Other modules push values onto the bus.

```
define( 'pusher', [ 'bus' ], function( bus ){
    // ...
    bus.push( value );
    // ...
} );
```

While other modules listen for values.

```
define( 'listener', [ 'bus' ], function( bus ){
    bus.onValue( function( value ){
        // Consume value
    } );
} );
```

Any modules that are currently loaded receive the pushed value; however any modules loaded afterwards do not.

I tried creating a `Bacon.Property` to hold the current value.

```
define( 'bus', [ 'bacon' ], function( Bacon ){
    var bus = new Bacon.Bus();

    bus.current = bus.toProperty();

    return bus;
} );

// The pusher is unchanged

define( 'listener', [ 'bus' ], function( bus ){
    bus.current.onValue( function( value ){
        // Consume value
    } );
} );
```

This still did not solve the problem though. Whether I attach `onValue` to `bus` or `bus.current`, modules loaded after the fact do not get triggered.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please show us the listener code (i.e., the asynchronously loaded module)?

Comment: I added an example listener module. Whether the listener is loaded at the time of the `push` or after the fact, the code is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is practically the same old laziness issue: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ#why-isnt-my-property-updated

As a workaround, you can add a no-op subscriber to the property to make sure it gets updated even when there are no actual subscribers. Or you can use https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.model

Comment: Thanks! That did indeed solve my issue. I added an empty `onValue` to `current` in the `bus` module and that worked. I will look into using `Bacon.Model`.